# Add graphics design to Magento site's background

Tags: layout, design

please visit this link :

http://www.toysrus.com/ on the left side of the site, you can see

some star marks and design did by graphics team.

I want to know how to do as like that in magento site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about css not about magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the container's width, so you could add a centered body background image with the desired design on both sides of the image, left and right of an empty space which is your containers width, like the toysrus site:

http://www.toysrus.com/graphics/media/trus/livecode/RD_2013/TRU/TRU_HP_Gutter_NEW/bg_gutter.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Add this to one of your css file:

```
body {
    background: url(http://www.toysrus.com/graphics/media/trus/livecode/RD_2013/TRU/TRU_HP_Gutter_NEW/bg_gutter.jpg) top center #FFFFFF no-repeat scroll !important;
}
```

and you will get the exact same background.
Of course you should use your own image. In this case you can use the `url` in the background property with a relative path to your image.